# EF AND MVC - Passing Repositories through controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a MVC app that uses the Entity Framework ORM. Everything is working as expected - however, on every new controller I initialise a new Repository

```
    public AController()
        : this(new ARepository())

     public AController(IA _A)
     {
       this.m_A = _A
     }
```

But when initialising the new Repository, it needs to get the entites from the database and in one Repository, this needs to get over 5000+ entities

```
list<object> ob = m_A.entity.ToList(); // This now has over 5000+ items
```

The obvious problem is when the user POSTS or GETS to these controllers, its going to do this all the time, and of course, as I am initialising a new Repository on the controller, its slowing down the performance and I cannot use `local` cache that would speed things up.

Is there a way I can send the Repository through to each controller or anyway I can speed up the EF fetching?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could instantiate your repository using dependency injection that would instantiate it as a singleton object. If you don't plan to use DI container, then you could create a static instance in some project that can be seen/shared in the controllers:

```
private static IMyRepository _instance;

public IMyRepository Repository
{
    get 
    {
        if (_instance == null)
        {
            _instance = new SomeRepositoryObject();
        }

        return _instance;
    }
}
```

In your case, because of the initialization, you could actually create a method rather than a property and after the object is created, you would call your method to load 5000+ objects.